# React JS: How to make component for different actions without multiple copy-paste?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Could you please help me. I made 2 files: editIcon.js and deleteIcon.js. Almost all code is similar except text in button. How to properly make the “Icon” component for different tasks and different actions without multiple copy-paste?

editIcon.js:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import '../main.css';

import img from './editIcon.png';

const EditIcon = ({ id, text, handleClick }) => (
   <img
        src={img}
        text={text}
        alt={text}
        title={text}
        onClick={() => { if (handleClick) return handleClick(id) }}
        key={`edit_icon_${id}`}
        className='action-icon'
    />    
)


EditIcon.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string,
    text: PropTypes.string,
    handleClick: PropTypes.func,
    handleDel: PropTypes.func
};

EditIcon.defaultProps = {
    id: '',
    text: 'Edit',
    handleClick: null
};


export default EditIcon;
```

deleteIcon.js:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import '../main.css';

import img from './delIcon.png';

const DelIcon = ({ id, text, handleClick }) => (
    <img
        src={img}
        text={text}
        alt={text}
        title={text}
        onClick={() => { if (handleClick) return handleClick(id) }}
        key={`del_icon_${id}`}
        className='action-icon'
    />

)


DelIcon.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string,
    text: PropTypes.string,
    handleClick: PropTypes.func,
    handleDel: PropTypes.func
};

DelIcon.defaultProps = {
    id: '',
    text: 'Delete',
    handleClick: null
};


export default DelIcon;
```

Almost all code is similar except text in button. How to properly make the “Icon” component for different tasks and different actions without multiple copy-paste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, these can definitely be combined into the same component. I would just add a type prop to the component so that you can distinguish between "edit" and "delete". Wherever you render the component from you pass in the correct value for the type prop.

```
const SomeComponent = () => {

  return (
    <Icon id={id} text={text} handleClick={handleClick} type="edit"/>
  )
}
```

```
const SomeOtherComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Icon id={id} text={text} handleClick={handleClick} type="delete" />
  )
}
```

Then in your `Icon` component, you can do some conditional values depending on the `type` prop:

```
import editImg from './editIcon.png';
import deleteImg from './delIcon.png';

const EditIcon = ({ id, text, handleClick, type }) => (
   <img
        src={type === 'edit'? editImg: deleteImg}
        text={type === 'edit'? 'Edit' : 'Delete'}
        alt={text}
        title={text}
        onClick={() => { if (handleClick) return handleClick(id) }}
        key={type === 'edit'? `edit_icon_${id}` : `del_icon_${id}`}
        className='action-icon'
    />    
)
```